# How to write a simple cake module

Tags: cakebuild

I want to change the way cake logs results, so I must write a ["module"](https://cakebuild.net/docs/extending/modules/resources).

Unfortuntely there is no documentation for that, just a long and outdated (4+ years) video. I also looked at [other](https://cakebuild.net/extensions/) modules, but they are too complicated - it's hard to tell the difference between the actual module stuff (what I'm interested in) and the library's domain code (what I'm not interested in).

Is there current documentation or a simple example for a "hello world" module?

Comment: While the video that you reference is a few years old now, the core fundamentals of it are still true today. Alistair shows in the first 19 minutes of the video how to create a simple addition to the log output from Cake. What other information are you looking for, that isn't covered in the video?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark There have been major changes (and deprecations) from what I can tell from the repo, so I didn't realise such an old video was still correct. I'll have another look. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, since the video was created, there have been a number of changes in Cake, however, if you follow along the video, replacing specific version numbers with the latest available, and also looking at what devlead has said below, I believe you should still get a lot of information from the video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Cake module is a .NET assembly that can replace core internal features of Cake. Simplified a module declares which feature it wants to replace, it does so by registering that a core Cake interface should use another concrete implementation. Then during Cake startup Cake bootstraps by acquiring modules from NuGet and scans each module for Cake modules, instantiates modules and invokes each modules registrations which results in modifying Cake dependency injection to prefer module implementation over built-in.

First of all a module needs an assembly level attribute declaring which modules it contains and each module needs to implement the `ICakeModule` interface, this could look something like

```cs
using System;
using Cake.Core;
using Cake.Core.Annotations;
using Cake.Core.Composition;
using Cake.Core.Diagnostics;
[assembly: CakeModule(typeof(Cake. CustomLog.Module.CustomLogModule))]
namespace Cake.CustomLog.Module
{
    public class CustomLogModule : ICakeModule
    {
        public void Register(ICakeContainerRegistrar registrar)
        {
            if (registrar is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(registrar));
            }

            registrar.RegisterType<CustomLog>().As<ICakeLog>().Singleton();
        }
    }
}
```

The assembly name needs follow the naming convention of `Cake.{module name}.Module` i.e. `Cake.CustomLog.Module`

Modules are bootstrapped in scripts using the `#module` directive i.e.

```cs
#module nuget:?package=Cake.CustomLog.Module&version=1.0
```

The `Cake.Core` assembly contains core interfaces and implementations, so module needs to reference it and ideally the same version as the runner you plan to use it on, it can be found on NuGet at
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.Core

To get a sense of which interfaces used you can look at one of the runners i.e. Cake.Tool to get a sense of what's registered in the IoC

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/src/Cake/Program.cs
and
https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/src/Cake/Infrastructure/ContainerConfigurator.cs
good starting points.

A dated/unfinished but fairly minimal module example can be found here
https://github.com/devlead/Cake.LightModeConsole.Module

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. I'm sure it'll help others too.